# how to check the default value of a radiobutton tag and display its related contents?

Tags: javascript, html

below is the code to check a default value for the radiobutton tag by giving checked="checked", but i am not able to display the related form by default, it can be displayed only when i click on it, how to display anyone of these forms by default ?

HTML:

```
    <form>
  <label><input value="1" type="radio" name="formselector" checked="checked" onclick="displayForm(this)">Old Definitions</label>    
  <label><input value="2" type="radio" name="formselector" onclick="displayForm(this)">New Definition</label> 

  </form>

 <panel method="post" style="visibility:hidden" id="form1" name="form1">
 <table style="width:100%;">
   <tr>
    <th ><span class="dropt">ID Reserve Tracks</th>
  <td> 
      <input id="idtracks" autocomplete="off" name="idtracks" type="text" maxlength="50" >
 </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </panel>
   <panel style="visibility:hidden" id="form2">
   <table style="width:100%;">
   <th ><span class="dropt">MD Reserve Tracks</th>
  <td>
  <input id="mdtracks" autocomplete="off" name="mdtracks" type="text" maxlength="50" >
  </td>
   </table>
    </panel>
```

JavaScript:

```
         function displayForm(c){
            if(c.value == "1"){
                document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility='visible';
                document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility='collapse';
            }
            else if(c.value =="2"){
                document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility='collapse';
                document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility='visible';
            }
            else{
            }
        }
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uLkHk/

Comment: Why not just set the default panel's visibility to visible in the HTML?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, and what's a `panel` element supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

Your Html is not well formed, you should improve that. 
To make it work as you want, just do not set the option checked in HTML. Then select it in JavaScript, calling the Click method.
See this, I modified a little your HTML, and it works.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form>
    <label>
        <input value="1" type="radio" id="radioOld" name="formselector" onclick="displayForm(this)" />Old
        Definitions</label>
    <label>
        <input value="2" type="radio" id="radioNew" name="formselector" onclick="displayForm(this)" />New
        Definition</label>
    </form>
    <form method="post" style="visibility: hidden" id="form1" name="form1">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="dropt">ID Reserve Tracks</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idtracks" autocomplete="off" name="idtracks" type="text" maxlength="50" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <form style="visibility: hidden" id="form2">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span class="dropt">MD Reserve Tracks</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="mdtracks" autocomplete="off" name="mdtracks" type="text" maxlength="50" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        function displayForm(c) {
            if (c.value == "1") {
                document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility = 'collapse';
            }
            else if (c.value == "2") {
                document.getElementById("form1").style.visibility = 'collapse';
                document.getElementById("form2").style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
            else {
            }
        }   
    </script>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('radioOld').click();

        //document.getElementById('radioOld').checked = true;
        //var theDefaultOption = document.getElementById('formselector');
        //displayForm(theDefaultOption);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can simply set the default panel's visibility to visible in the HTML as Barmar said.